# SwiftUI - How to change the specific icon color in the list

Tags: swiftui

I would like to change the specific icon color to .red at the time of selecting that icon from the list. For example when I select the car icon I want the car icon to be red and other icons to remain unchanged.

However when I am selecting car icon all the icons colors is changing to red.

Following is the code.

```
import SwiftUI

enum icon: String, CaseIterable {
    case gear, bus, questionmark, car,
         lightbulb
    
   
}
struct ContentView: View {
    let iconColunm: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        
    ]
    
    @State private var categoryName:String = ""
    @State private var categorySFIcon:String?
    @State private var selectedIcon:String = ""
    @State private var iconColor: Color = .gray
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Category Name", text: $categoryName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                    Section {
                        List {
                            LazyVGrid(columns: iconColunm) {
                                ForEach(icon.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { icon in
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: icon.rawValue)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                                            .foregroundColor(iconColor)
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                                categorySFIcon = icon.rawValue
                                                self.iconColor = .red
                                            }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text("Select Icon's Category")
                    }
                    Section("Selected Category") {
                        Text(categorySFIcon ?? "")
                    }
                    
                }.navigationTitle("Add Category")
            }
        }
            }
}
struct addCategoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Appreciate your support! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please write your enum capitalized, as this is a [coding convention](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/enumerations/).

Second, I would change your code to this:

```
enum Icon: String, CaseIterable {
    case gear, bus, questionmark, car, lightbulb
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let iconColunm: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        
    ]
    
    @State private var categoryName: String = ""
    @State private var categorySFIcon: String?
    @State var selectedIcon: Icon
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Category Name", text: $categoryName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                    Section {
                        List {
                            LazyVGrid(columns: iconColunm) {
                                ForEach(Icon.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { icon in
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: icon.rawValue)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                                            .foregroundColor(selectedIcon == icon ? .red : .gray)
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                                selectedIcon = icon
                                            }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text("Select Icon's Category")
                    }
                    Section("Selected Category") {
                        Text(categorySFIcon ?? "")
                    }
                    
                }.navigationTitle("Add Category")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(selectedIcon: .gear)
    }
}
```

In here we changed some of the variables and changed the code for the color change. The `onTapGesture` changes the `selectedIcon` to the icon inside the `ForEach` and the `foregroundColor` changes based on the `selectedIcon`.

At the bottom, we will now need a `selectedIcon` inside the `Preview`, because we don't have a value for now.